# how to call variable in jsx

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have defined a variable, and I am setting the contents of the variable = the image url like so:

```
  var regData = ""
firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid).get().then((doc) => { 

      console.log(doc.data().registeringFlag); 
      regData = doc.data().registeringFlag;
      console.log("reg data " + regData)

      if (regData == "yes"){
        regData = "https://i.gifer.com/Z23Y.gif"

        firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(user.uid).set({
          registeringFlag: "no"
      })
    }
})
```

then I am trying to access the contents of `regData` inside my jsx code, like so:

```
 return (
    
    <BottomTabsWithFullHeightContent onChange={ (activeKey) => pushHistoryForTab(props.history, activeKey) } activeKey={props.showTab}>

      <div className="container"><img src={ regData } width="300px" height="300px"/></div>

    </BottomTabsWithFullHeightContent>
    
  )
}
```

however, it is not actually showing the image on screen like it is supposed to. It gives me:

`TypeError: null is not an object`

How do I fix this?

here's the try with .then:

```
var regData = ""
firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid).get().then((doc) => { 

      console.log(doc.data().registeringFlag); 
      regData = doc.data().registeringFlag;
      console.log("reg data " + regData)

      if (regData == "yes"){
        regData = '"https://i.gifer.com/Z23Y.gif"'

        firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(user.uid).set({
          registeringFlag: "no"
      })
    }
}).then (() => {


  return (
    
    <BottomTabsWithFullHeightContent onChange={ (activeKey) => pushHistoryForTab(props.history, activeKey) } activeKey={props.showTab}>
      <TabPane tab={ <VerticalCaptionedIcon type="contacts" theme="filled" caption="Clients" /> } key={ routes.CLIENTS }>
        <ClientTabContent { ...props }/>
      </TabPane>
      <TabPane tab={ <VerticalCaptionedIcon type="file-text" theme="filled" caption="Estimates" /> } key={ routes.ESTIMATES }>
        <EstimateTabContent { ... props }/>
      </TabPane>
      <TabPane tab={ <VerticalCaptionedIcon type="form" caption="Jobs" /> } key={ routes.JOBS }>
        <JobTabContent { ... props }/>
      </TabPane>
      <TabPane tab={ <VerticalCaptionedIcon type="user" caption="Profile" /> } key={ routes.PROFILE }>
        <UserProfileContent { ... props }/>
      </TabPane>
      

      <div className="container"><img src={ regData }width="300px" height="300px"/></div>
      { console.log("rd: " + regData) }

    </BottomTabsWithFullHeightContent>
    
  )
})

}
```

Comment: could you please create a sandbox of your issue?

Comment: please console the variable `regData` before return, what it's showing?

Comment: @SifatHaque it is actually logging an empty value. I logged it under the `      <div className="container"><img src={ regData } width="300px" height="300px"/></div>
`. I just noticed int eh logs that it is logging `console.log("reg data " + regData)` before it is  logging what I just logged under the div. Maybe a timing issue?

Comment: Fetching from firestore is asynchronous. Any code that needs to use the resulting value needs to be inside the `.then` callback. For a react component, you'll probably put a call to set state inside the `.then` callback, and then anything else just pays attention to the state variable.

Comment: @NicholasTower oh okay, that makes sense actually. So I tried that, but It says `Error: MainPage(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` I've edited my question to show what I did

Answer (score 1):

You need to use component level state to manipulate dynamic async data. Here is the modified version of your code.

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const [regData, setRegData] = useState('');

firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid).get().then((doc) => { 
      setRegData(doc.data().registeringFlag);

      if (regData == "yes"){
        setRegData("https://i.gifer.com/Z23Y.gif");
        firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(user.uid).set({
          registeringFlag: "no"
      })
    }
})


 return (
    
    <BottomTabsWithFullHeightContent onChange={ (activeKey) => pushHistoryForTab(props.history, activeKey) } activeKey={props.showTab}>

   {regData && <div className="container"><img src={ regData } width="300px" height="300px"/></div>}

    </BottomTabsWithFullHeightContent>
    
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the part where you set ` regData = doc.data().registeringFlag;`, gives an error in my console, stating `[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: "regData" is read-only`. do you have any ideas?

Comment: upss sorry, if you want to assign something to regData then you need to use `setRegData`.
like this  `setRegData(doc.data().registeringFlag);`